# メッセージソースに「_ja」を含めると読めない

Tags: java, spring-boot

お世話になります。

spring boot のメッセージソースを利用するところではまっています。

以下のサイトを参考にサンプルを作りましたが、正しく動きません。
https://web-dev.hatenablog.com/entry/spring-boot/intro/message-source

messages_ja.properties　に　「msg1=メッセージ」のように設定して、コントローラクラスから、「msg.getMessage("msg1", null, Locale.JAPAN);」(msgはメッセージソースのインスタンス)した場合、以下のような例外が発生してしまいます。

org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'msg1' for locale 'ja_JP'.

messages_ja.properties を messages.properties に変更すると正しく取得できます。

他に、コントローラでロケールを受け取り、標準出力すると「ja」と表示されることを確認しています。

原因と思われるものは何でしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。

追記：
・application.properties の内容は「spring.messages.basename=messages」の一行だけです。
・Spring boot のバージョンは v2.0.3.RELEASE です。

若干自己解決：
「messages_ja.properties」のファイルと同じ場所に、空の「messages.properties」ファイルを置いたら、メッセージが取得できるようになりました。不思議。

Comment: `application.properties`または`application.yml`に追記した定義も載せていただけますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locale.JAPANで対応するプロパティは
messages_ja_JP.properties
となります。

Locale.JAPANESE は
messages_ja.properties
です。
なので、今のファイル名のまま使うためにはJAPANESE の方を使ってください。

また、_ja を省略するとデフォルトとして使われるため、取得可能になったはずです。

追記
springでAutoConfigureにてBeanを注入した場合、デフォルトのプロパティがないとだめなようです。
messages.propertiesがない場合はDelegatingMessageSource,message.properiesがある場合はResourceBundleMessageSourceがBeanとして注入されます。

もしmessages.propertiesを使いたくない場合は自分で注入するためのBeanを設定したほうが良さそうです。

Comment: Locale.JAPAN のままでファイル名を「messages_ja_JP.properties」にしても現象は同じでした。Locale.JAPANESE に変更してファイル名を「messages_ja.properties」でもダメです。orz

Comment: @yamada100 自動でMessageSourceを定義していると、デフォルトのpropertiesファイルが必要なようです。回答を更新しました。

Comment: そういうとことなのですね！ありがとうございました。